# How to share my iphone app still ind development using simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I am developing an iphone app and I need to share this app with some people that don't even have an iPhone or people that don't want to use their personal phone for testing purposes.

So, I would like to understand if it is possible to send them instructions how to run the simulator and bypassing the developer enrollment process for each of them.

Is that possible ? Android is so easy but I am facing issues with iOS.

Thanks a lot community!

Answer (score 0):

Do they have MACs? Do you care about sharing your source code?  Because you can have them install XCode, and clone your development project from GitHub or download your project files and then build/run the app in the simulator.  Otherwise they're going to *have* to use their personal devices and download an archive build that you make.

Comment: some of them do. However, is possible to the app without re-building it ? I am assuming no.

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to test it without re-building it?  You can either send an archived build someone with an iOS device, or you can get the app file from xcode and send it to someone who has a MAC and xcode and installed, and they can drop it on the simulator.  See here for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819516/xcode-build-archive-app-for-anyone-to-run-in-a-simulator